# products not showing up in magento backend with given sku but exist

Tags: magento

When i am trying to find a product given sku like "xyz345" in admin panel not gives any record but when i am trying to find this product with the same sku in Global Record Search then gives me the record for this product. I did not actually understand where this product saved in backend. Can anyone help me out of this problem ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

try to log/get the details of that product. You will see some required attributes are missing. Set those attributes, and you will see your products.

I guess you have imported products or created programatically.